# Git ignore file not working properly in root directory

Tags: git

I have a gitignore file in root directory and its not working. Using source tree with Bitbucket.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You will need to commit your gitignore first before it'll work.

Comment: @Chris I do not use cmd for git mate, so I can't understand what to do. I use sourcetree.

Comment: @Bjorn, that's not correct. `.gitignore` files don't have to be committed to take effect. (Though it's a good idea to commit them anyway; that's their purpose: to be a shared ignore mechanism. Private ignores can go into `.git/info/exclude`.)

Comment: @Waleed, then tag your question with the SourceTree tag. It's probably a good idea to learn enough Git to understand the proposed duplicate, though. This question has been asked and answered hundreds of times on Stack Overflow. It doesn't need to be asked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For those who are using Bitbucket** and not the commands with git. You need to right click on the file while committing and choose option **'Stop Tracking'**. This will stop tracking this file as long as it is in gitignore. Once you remove gitignore it will start tacking again.

Git tends to not ignore files that are already committed to a repository. So you need to ignore them explicitly, if using Bitbucket use stop tracking option.